# Using tenure in place of stint

Tags: word-usage

Can we replace **"stint"** by **"tenure"** in the following sentence?

> > John's **stint** as an overseer in that village is over. Now, he is deputed as an overseer in a nearby city.

As per [Oxford](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/tenure), tenure means **"The holding of an office."**

Now, the above sentence says that John is still an overseer in his company, but he is now transferred to another location. So, by "tenure" do we just consider the position of an employee or his position and place of work, both are considered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well traditionally by tenure, you think of a job like a professor, in other words a position and place of work over a period of time.

If the job position remains the same but the place of work changes (say, transfer to another job site within the same company), then you wouldn't say your tenure has ended, as that implies you've lost your job.

On a similar note, if you perform the same duty for two separate institutions (for instance professor for one university and then later professor for another), you *would* consider that a change in tenure.

So by that reasoning, tenure is strongly associated with your job.  If your job ends, so does your tenure.  If you are moved to a new location but wouldn't consider your job ended, neither has your tenure ended.

So to answer your question, I would say yes only if we're assuming that the role of overseer is for a new company.  If it is for the same company, then no.